# Cannot Find Text of Dynamically created TextBox in asp Table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, dynamic

I have an asp table with a few headers and textboxes. I can dynamically add a number of rows (each row contains 5 textboxes) and set the id of each textbox within the rows.

My problem though, is that I cannot find the values of these dynamic textbox controls when I need them on button click.

Here's my code for asp table:

```
<asp:Table ID="appendMe" runat="server">

                <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Address"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="City"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="State"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Zip"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Start Date(s)"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="ESID"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                </asp:TableHeaderRow>

                <asp:TableRow ID="row1" runat="server">
                    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="ASPxAddress1Txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="ASPxCity1Txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="ASPxState1Txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="ASPxZip1Txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID ="ASPxStartDate1Txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="ASPxESID1Txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
```

Heres my code to dynamically add textboxes to the aboves table:

```
protected void btnAddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(ASPxLocationCountTxt.Text, out n);
            if (isNumeric)
            {
                errorLbl.Text = "";
                
                for (int counter = 0; counter < n; counter++)
                {
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow();

                    TableCell AddressCell = new TableCell();
                    TableCell CityCell = new TableCell();
                    TableCell StateCell = new TableCell();
                    TableCell ZipCell = new TableCell();
                    TableCell DateCell = new TableCell();
                    TableCell ESIDCell = new TableCell();

                    TextBox addressTxt = new TextBox();
                    addressTxt.ID = "ASPxAddress" + (counter + 2).ToString() + "Txt";
                    addressTxt.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

                    TextBox cityTxt = new TextBox();
                    cityTxt.ID = "ASPxCity" + (counter + 2).ToString() + "Txt";
                    cityTxt.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

                    TextBox stateTxt = new TextBox();
                    stateTxt.ID = "ASPxState" + (counter + 2).ToString() + "Txt";
                    stateTxt.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

                    TextBox zipTxt = new TextBox();
                    zipTxt.ID = "ASPxZip" + (counter + 2).ToString() + "Txt";
                    zipTxt.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

                    TextBox dateTxt = new TextBox();
                    dateTxt.ID = "ASPxStartDate" + (counter + 2).ToString() + "Txt";
                    dateTxt.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

                    TextBox esidTxt = new TextBox();
                    esidTxt.ID = "ASPxESID" + (counter + 2).ToString() + "Txt";
                    esidTxt.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

                    //add textboxes to cells
                    AddressCell.Controls.Add(addressTxt);
                    CityCell.Controls.Add(cityTxt);
                    StateCell.Controls.Add(stateTxt);
                    ZipCell.Controls.Add(zipTxt);
                    DateCell.Controls.Add(dateTxt);
                    ESIDCell.Controls.Add(esidTxt);

                    //add cells to row
                    tr.Cells.Add(AddressCell);
                    tr.Cells.Add(CityCell);
                    tr.Cells.Add(StateCell);
                    tr.Cells.Add(ZipCell);
                    tr.Cells.Add(DateCell);
                    tr.Cells.Add(ESIDCell);

                    appendMe.Rows.Add(tr);
                }
            } else 
            { 
                errorLbl.Text = "You have to enter a numeric value";
            }
        }
```

Now, i can find values for my hardcoded textboxes, but for dynamic textboxes i get **null** every time. Ive tried various methods without success

Heres my code to find values:

```
 for (int i =1; i<=n+1; i++)
            {
                TextBox address = (TextBox)appendMe.FindControl("ASPxAddress" + i.ToString() + "Txt");
                TextBox city = (TextBox)appendMe.FindControl("ASPxCity" + i.ToString() + "Txt");
                TextBox state = (TextBox)appendMe.FindControl("ASPxState" + i.ToString() + "Txt");
                TextBox zip = (TextBox)appendMe.FindControl("ASPxZip" + i.ToString() + "Txt");
                TextBox esid = (TextBox)appendMe.FindControl("ASPxESID" + i.ToString() + "Txt");

                
                htmlTable += "<tr><td>" + address.Text + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + city.Text + "</td><td>" + state.Text + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + zip.Text + "</td><td>" + esid.Text + "</td></tr>";
            }
```

i get error 'address is null' , and i assume it will happen with the rest aswell

Comment: Where is the code that you are trying to get tetboxes by Id's?

Comment: @SelimYıldız , I just added, sorry.

Comment: What is `this.appendMe`?

Comment: @SelimYıldız  it previously was just appendMe, which also works, but that is the asp table im refering to. The asp table's ID is 'appendMe'